# Flutter GetX Provider & GetConnect Settings

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-http

I created a Flutter project with GetX CLI. Then i created a provider with get generate model. But i have problems with provider:

1. When i bind it with lazyPut, onInit() never works.
2. When i bind it with put, onInit() works but httpClient.defaultDecoder section does
   not executed.
3. When i bind it with put, onInit() works and httpClient.baseUrl is adjusted but i can't read it in getFaculties. It seems like null in global.
4. When i put httpClient.defaultDecoder and httpClient.baseUrl in getFaculties, works well. But doesn't seem like the right way.

Am i doing something wrong or is it about GetConnect? Thanks in advance.

Provider:

```
    class FacultyProvider extends GetConnect {
    @override
    void onInit() {

    print('PROVIDER INIT!'); // Works with Get.put(FacultyProvider()) in Bindings

    httpClient.defaultDecoder = (map) { // NEVER WORKS
      if (map is Map<String, dynamic>) {
        print('MAP!');
        return Faculty.fromJson(map);
      }

      if (map is List) {
        print('LIST!');
        return map.map((item) => Faculty.fromJson(item)).toList();
      }
    };
    httpClient.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/public';
    }

    Future<List<Faculty>> getFaculties(bool cache) async {

      print(httpClient.baseUrl); // ALWAYS NULL

      final response = await httpClient.get('/faculties/true'); // NO HOST ERROR
      return response.body; // TYPE ERRORS because of defaultDecoder section didn't run
    }
```

Bindings:

```
    class FacultiesBinding extends Bindings {
      @override
      void dependencies() {
      Get.put(FacultyProvider());
      // Get.lazyPut<FacultyProvider>(() => FacultyProvider());
      Get.lazyPut<FacultiesController>(() => FacultiesController());
    }
```

Comment: Where are you using `FacultyProvider`?

Comment: In controller. GetX call Bindings in Route. Btw, i couldn't find a fix. I switched to Dio for api calls.

Comment: It would be grate if you include your controller codes.